# Cloud Dataflow performance issue while writing to BigQuery

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, profiling, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read and write it to BigQuery with Cloud Dataflow (Beam Python SDK).

It is taking almost 30 minutes for reading and writing 20 million records (~ 80 MBs).

Looking at dataflow DAG I can see it is taking most of the time at converting each CSV line to BQ Row.

[image]

Below is the code snippet for doing the same :

```
beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.parse_record_string(s,data_ingestion.stg_schema_dict)) 

    def parse_record_string(self, string_input,schema_dict): 

        for idx,(x,key) in enumerate(zip(imm_input,schema_dict)):
            key = key.strip()
            datatype = schema_dict[key].strip()
            if key == 'HASH_ID' and datatype != 'STRING':
                hash_id = hash(''.join(imm_input[1:idx]))
                row_dict[key] = hash_id
            else:
                if x:
                    x = x.decode('utf-8').strip()
                    row_dict[key] = x
                else:
                    row_dict[key] = None
                    #row_dict[key] = ''
        return row_dict
```

Apart from map transform , I have used ParDo and Flatmap also. All of them are producing same result.

Please suggest any possible tuning to reduce time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FlatMap and Map are all backed by ParDo. Beam automatically converts from Python Dicts to TableRow when writing to BQ.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is compute intensive when you look at it. For each of your 20M of line, you perform:

- A for loop (how many element on each line?)
- A zip and enumerate
- On each element on the loop

  - You perform 2 strips (which are loop on the string to remove spaces)
  - A join on a slice (which are 2 loops) -> how often this condition is true ?
  - Another strip in other case

Python is wonderful and very convenient with many helpers. However, take care of the trap of this easiness and evaluate correctly the complexity of your algorithm.

If you know Java, try it out. It could be far more efficient.

Comment: Completely agree, you can  verify the [Google BigQuery I/O connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/) which include built-in transforms that can read data from and write data to Google BigQuery tables.